# Hide/Unhide Command Button based on dynamically changing cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create some VBA code that will hide a command button based on a cell's value.

If cell "S17"= "(All)" then the command button should be hidden, otherwise it can remain visible.

As I stated, the value in cell S17 changes dynamically, so the code will need to update whenever the user makes a change.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Sheet3.Range("S17").Value = "(All)" Then
 CommandButton6.Visible = False
Else
 CommandButton6.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Currently this isn't doing anything. If cell S17 = "(All)" the command button is still visible.

Comment: You might want to bail out early when `Target` isn't `Sheet3!S17`...

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry still fairly new to VBA.

Comment: Are you changing cell S17 directly, or is the result of a formula?

Comment: The result of a formula

Comment: Try handling `Worksheet_Calculate` instead.

Comment: This works! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("S17") Then

If Target.Value = "(All)" Then
CommandButton6.Visible = False

Else

CommandButton6.Visible = True

End If

End If

End Sub
```